# Google Cloud IKEv2 VPN on Ubuntu Compute Engine VPS

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, google-cloud-platform, vps

As I stated in the title, I am installing the strongSwan and configure the IKEV2 VPN on the VPS.

But, as you know, GCP has its firewall rules, which I am not familiar with that.

I am using this script to install strongSwan IKEV2 VPN (https://github.com/truemetal/ikev2_vpn)

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport  500 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 4500 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in  --proto esp -s 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d 10.10.10.10/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s 10.10.10.10/24 -o eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

Someone can help me to apply those rules into GCP firewall rules?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#ingress_cases) firewall rules always allow incoming packets from a source to destination within the VPC network whereas egress do the opposite. Please follow the article [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules) for more information. Advanced settings and configurations regarding IKE, please go through [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/advanced#configuring_ike_including_multiple_subnet_support).